# How to find the current exact download rate in Android (wifi and Mobile Data)?

Tags: android

I am making an application that monitors the traffic and when the speed reaches bellow 5 kbps, does something.
I can't find a way to get the exact download rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask` that from time to time measures how much of the downloaded file has been downloaded in a period of time. The accuracy of this approach will depend on how often do you measure the downloaded difference in size of the downloaded time. The more times you measure, more accuracy you'll have but as downside it might affect your performance if you do such task very often.

Comment: I would use something decoupled from the UI lifecycle like a service or intent-service then report back the results to the UI. AsyncTask is something I seldom use these days.

Comment: @James I did not ask the question? And I was the ones who submitted the close flag....